# Merge results from two different selects to one get result set

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

I have two selects in my MyBatis mapper XML file as shown below. I have three scenarios:

1. Get results from only the first select - `getResultsA`
2. Get results from only the second select - `getResultsB`
3. Combine both first and second select - `getResultsAAndB`

Here is my XML:

```
<select id="getResultsA" resultMap="myResultMap" parameterType="MyParameters">
   <!-- select statement 1 -->
</select>

<select id="getResultsB" resultMap="myResultMap" parameterType="MyParameters">
   <!-- select statement 2 -->
</select>

<select id="getResultsAAndB" resultMap="myResultMap" parameterType="MyParameters">
   <!-- NEED TO MERGE RESULTS FROM BOTH getResultsA & getResultsB-->
</select>
```

For scenario 1 and 2, I can use the respective selects separately. How do I achieve the third scenario without having to write a new SQL statement with union? I am currently achieving this by two separate mapper calls and then using `list.addall(anotherList)` in Java to merge the results. In other words, I just need to merge results from both the selects, and result map being the same, I think this should be possible.

Comment: I doubt there is any generic solution to this other that ones that you've already mentioned (SQL `UNION` or Java's `addAll()`).
Please post your select statements, maybe some problem-specific solution exists for them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever been thought about adding a flag property in you `MyParameters`? Then you can merge all above 3 SQLs into one:-

```
<select id="getResultsAOrBOrAB" resultMap="myResultMap" parameterType="MyParameters">
   SELECT * FROM TABLE
   <trim prefix="WHERE" prefixOverrides="OR">
      <if test="flag == 'A' or flag == 'AB'">
        <!-- criteria statement 1 -->
      </if>
      <if test="flag == 'B' or flag == 'AB'">
        OR <!-- criteria statement 2 -->
      </if>
</select>
```